# Using OperatingSystemMXBean in android

Tags: android

I wanted to use OperatingSystemMXBean in my android code for getting cpu usage and i am using this `import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;`

It is showing an error for com.sun.management. Is there something i need to do or add a jar for it?

Comment: You get the CPU usage in Android Studio as well. [Check](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing from `com.sun` is in [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html). I am not aware of any JAR that works on Android and can be legitimately licensed for use by SDK apps that would offer any `com.sun` classes, let alone the one that you seek.

Comment: Yeah even I had this same doubt and now you confirmed it. Thank you :)